# CoreData one-to-many and inverse relationship problem

Tags: iphone, core-data

I am trying to import a set of data into a CoreData persistentStore. This is read-only data that will be presented to the user at run-time.

I have an entity called "Category" that has a one-to-many relationship with an entity called "Item", which in turn has an inverse relationship to a Category.

As I add Items to the context, how do I associate them with the correct Category? I can see in the SQLite dB that it is done by adding a Category field to the Item table, and probably uses the Categories primary key for the relationship. But the PK is behind-the-scenes... is there a method for making the connection?

I also see in my Category class that there are methods generated by CoreData for adding Items, but I am assuming that these are alos behind-the-scene methods that allow CoreData to maintain the relationships:

```
    @interface Category (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addItemObject:(Item *)value;
- (void)removeItemObject:(Item *)value;
- (void)addItems:(NSSet *)value;
- (void)removeItems:(NSSet *)value;

@end
```

I read in the programing guide that CoreData takes care of the other side of the relationship automatically, but I can't figure out how do do the initial link to a Category as I add Items.

Thanks

jk

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are different possibilities. If you already have a Category object (for instance obtained through a fetch request), and assuming the variables

```
Category *category;
Item *item;
```

then you simply do the following:

```
item.category = category;
```

or

```
[category setValue: category forKey:@"category"];
```

and you are done, since Core Data automatically sets the inverse relationships.

If you do not have a Category object, or you want to insert a new one, do the following:

```
// Create a new instance of the entity 
Category *category = (Category *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Category" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
// add all of the category properties, then set the relationship
// for instance set the category name
[category setValue:@"myCategoryName" forKey:@"name"];
[category setValue:item forKey:@"item"];
```

Then you set this Category object for your Item object exactly as before.
Finally, the methods you have shown are not used behind the scenes by Core Data: these methods are available to you, so that you can also do the following:

```
[category addItemObject:item];
```

or the inverse:

```
[item addCategoryObject:category];
```

Comment: Thanks, Unforgiven. I had figured out most of this already from another post on another board, but your answer is clear as a bell. Wish Apples docs were better! Now I need to learn how to retrieve Items for a given category and I'm home free!

jk

Comment: You need to associate a NSPredicate to the fetch request you use to fetch objects from the Item entity. If your Category entity stores the name of the category as a property, you use the to-one relationship from Item to Category:NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"category.name LIKE %@", yourCategoryNameStringHere];

Simply associate this predicate to the fetch request you use to fetch objects from the Item entity.

Comment: Thanks again, Unforgiven. 
I discovered that you can also go from the other direction: if you have the Category, you can get an array of Items from the NSSet of the Categorie's Items property.

Comment: exactly, the object to fetch depends on the particular scenario your application is covering at the moment.